# How to implement sending a command from a page to Django via SSH?

Tags: python, django, ssh

How to implement sending a command from a page to Django via SSH?
It is necessary that the page has a button that, when clicked, sends a command via SSH to the Ubuntu virtual machine.

Good afternoon. Question regarding the implementation of SSH on pages in Django. It is necessary to assemble the command over SSH to the server.
There is such code using Paramiko:

views.py

```
class StartServer(server, view):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = AddServerForm(request.POST or None)
        servers = server.objects.all()
        context = {'form': form, 'csservers': servers}
        return render(request, 'csservers/server_detail.html', context)

    # def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # pass

    def start_server(i, request, pc):
        print(request.POST)
        if request.POST:
            server = Server.objects.get(id=pk)
            client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            client.connect(hostname=server.host, username=server.server_username, password=server.secret, port=server.port)
            standard input, standard output, standard output = client.exec_command('./<command>')
            data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
            client.close()
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <metacharset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{server.host}}
    {{server.port}}
    {{server.server_username}}
    {{server.secret}}

    <form action="{% url 'server_start' server.slug server.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" style="outline: none; border: none; background-color: red; color: #fff;">Start server</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I click on the button, it gives an error 405. I need to connect to the local Ubuntu machine via SSH and send the ./ command.
Is it possible to implement this idea in a more logical and laconic way, or is it possible to do it with the help of Paramiko?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. "_sending a command from a page to Django via SSH_" Do you mean you'll submit a form and that instead of making a POST request it will connect to the server using SSH? Why do you even want to do that? Django is a **web server** just implement logic to handle a POST request.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm sorry, I need to be able to perform certain requests on the server via SSH, for example, the server is started on a virtual machine like this "./csgoserver start". I need the "Start server" button on the server page, after clicking the button, the following happens: a connection to the virtual machine is made via SSH, then "./csgoserver start" is executed on the virtual machine. I have done this to the best of my ability at the moment. In view of this, I also ask a question, maybe someone experienced can suggest how to improve, something can use the best.